# What is wrong in my script in this Python 3.x program?

Tags: python-3.x

```
import random

word_list = ["elma", "armut","kalem"]
chosen_word = random.choice(word_list)

stages = ['''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 / \  |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
 /    |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|\  |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
 /|   |
      |
      |
=========''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
  |   |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
  O   |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''', '''
  +---+
  |   |
      |
      |
      |
      |
=========
''']


map_1 = []
count = 0
end = False
for x in range(len(chosen_word)):
    map_1.append("_")

if "_" not in map_1:
    end = True
    Print("YOU WON")
if count == 6 and "_" in map_1:
    print("YOU LOST")
    end = True

while end == False:
    guess = input("Guess a letter ").lower()
    count += 1
    print(stages[- count])
    for letter in chosen_word:
        
        if guess == letter:
            a = chosen_word.index(letter)
            map_1[a] = guess
            print(map_1)
        else:
            continue



print(map_1)
```

it does not stop when you guess all the letters,
it gives IndexError: list index out of range every time ı execute the program,I didn't write a part for what happens when you make a wrong guess now ı do the correct guess every time but still it ends like this.I just started the learn in this part ı am stuck ı don't know how to solve this.

Comment: Please don't post pictures of code but rather the code itself. Ideally, the question should be posted such that it's easy to reproduce the issue.

Comment: Please include your code in the post as text and not as an image. See [ask]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to move the conditions into the while loop, otherwise, the program doesn't skip the while loop (end always is False).

```py
while end == False:
    guess = input("Guess a letter ").lower()
    count += 1
    print(stages[- count])
    for letter in chosen_word:
        
        if guess == letter:
            a = chosen_word.index(letter)
            map_1[a] = guess
            print(map_1)
        else:
            continue

    //end for loop   
    if "_" not in map_1:
        end = True
        print("YOU WON")
    if count == 6 and "_" in map_1:
       print("YOU LOST")
       end = True
```